# Node.js local server css file doesn't inject

Tags: css, node.js, localhost, node.js-connect

My dir looks like that :

```
|-project
   -gulpfile.js  
   |-build
     -index.html
     |-js
       -app.min.js
       -vendors.min.js
     |-styles
       -all.css
       -vendors.min.css
```

I inject the css file with:

```
gulp.task('index',function () {
return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['http://localhost:5000/styles/all.css'], {read: false})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    .pipe(livereload());
})
```

I set up a local server with Node.js, when I do the request , the HTML file loads up, but the .css file doesn't connect for some reason.

I use this task for setting the server :

```
gulp.task('connect', function() {
 connect.server({
   root: 'build',
   livereload: true,
    port: 5000
 });
});
```

Comment: open up web browser's dev tools and check if relative paths are correct for css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use express frame work to achieve this

`Var express=require (express);
var app=express();
// Now here you can attach static files
app.use("../example.css",static("/..example"));`

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to serve up static files such as CSS, JS, or assets you will need to add them to your `index.html`, and your server will be responsible for serving up your assets. Gulp is a task runner, not a server, so you  will need to set up a simple HTTP server to serve up your assets. You can certainty build an HTTP server with vanilla Nodejs, but the easiest way to do this is with [Express](http://expressjs.com/). Your Express server
 might look something like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// serve static files in public/build directory
app.use(express.static('./build'));

// start the server on port 3000
const server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Then in your `index.html` be sure to link your CSS files with the link tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple HTTP Server</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Simple HTTP Server</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the reason for that is that by progress i will have many css files so i just need to inject them all by *.css

Answer (score 0):

To everyone that may encounter my problem,that would be the solution.

```
.pipe(inject(gulp.src(['build/styles/all.css'], {read: false}), {ignorePath: 'build'} ))
```